# Why is the following batch code not working when put in IF-statement?

Tags: batch-file

So i have this code to output the filesize of a file, then replace the file and check the size again:

```
FOR %%A IN (%userprofile%\remove.me) DO (
    set size=%%~zA
)
pause
echo  before:%size%
copy %userprofile%\copy.me %userprofile%\remove.me
pause
FOR %%B IN (%userprofile%\remove.me) DO (
    set size2=%%~zB
)
pause
echo after:%size2%
pause
exit
```

It works perfectly fine, but when i try to check if the remove.me file exists before executing the code it wont output the filesizes:

```
if EXIST %userprofile%\remove.me (
FOR %%A IN (%userprofile%\remove.me) DO (
    set size=%%~zA
)
pause
echo  before:%size%
copy %userprofile%\copy.me %userprofile%\remove.me
pause
FOR %%B IN (%userprofile%\remove.me) DO (
    set size2=%%~zB
)
pause
echo after:%size2%
pause
exit
)
```

It will just say

before:

after:

without the filesizes.
If i try to escape the brackets inside the code that gets run by the if-statement it will just return that (C:\Users\Myaccountname\remove.me) does not follow the syntax.

I can't figure out why this is happening and how to fix this. Don't judge me, im new to batch .-.

Comment: try with `if EXIST "%userprofile%\remove.me"` and `FOR %%A IN ("%userprofile%\remove.me")`

Comment: @npocmaka nothing changed :/

Comment: Ooh you need delayed expansion

Comment: @npocmaka added a setlocal ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION at the start of the script, nothing changed.

Comment: check my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are changing and accessing  value inside brackets context.So you need [delayed expansion](https://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html)

```
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
if EXIST "%userprofile%\remove.me" (
    FOR %%A IN ("%userprofile%\remove.me") DO (
        set size=%%~zA
    )
    pause
    echo  before:!size!
    copy "%userprofile%\copy.me" "%userprofile%\remove.me"
    pause
    FOR %%B IN ("%userprofile%\remove.me") DO (
        set size2=%%~zB
    )
    pause
    echo after:!size2!
    pause
    exit

)
```

Comment: with this code the batch console instantly closes after running 
"setlocal enableDelayedExpansion" :/

Comment: @Temm - check it now. By accidend I've left the last closing bracket outside of the code block.